# Rearrangement of Students (flaw in my solution)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> There are 11 students in a class including A, B and C. The 11 students have to form a straight line. Provided that A cannot be the first person in the line, what is the probability that in any random rearrangement of line, A comes before B and C.

For eg, this is a valid rearrangement (1-8 are other students)

1 2 3 A 4 5 C 6 7 B 8

Here's my solution -

Probability that A goes before B and C **without any restrictions** is $\frac13$. (Notice the symmetry. The answer will be same for B goes first and C goes first.)

Probability that A goes first without any restrictions is $\frac{1}{11}$

Hence the answer is

$$\frac13 - \frac{1}{11} = \frac{8}{33}$$

But the answer is $\frac{4}{15}$ according to my textbook. Please help me to find flaw in my solution.

Comment: Shouldnt the word rearrangement matter

Comment: At least, the answer must be x <1/3.

Answer (score 3):

See total ways of arranging anyhow is $10.10!$. Now the constrained ways .  As a A cannot be first so lets place A at 2 nd place so B,C has to come after let it be CB or BC it doesnt matter so we need to multiply all terms with $2!$ now as A is 2nd we have ${9\choose 2}.2!$ options for B,C and $8!$ for remaining now if A is at $3$ place then we have ${8\choose 2}.2!$ for B,C and $8!$ for others so this can be done for A till $9th$ place . i hope you know the reason . so our probability becomes $$\frac{(2!.8!.({9\choose 2}+{8\choose 2}+...+{2\choose 2})}{10.10!}=\frac{4}{15}$$

Comment: Be careful.  Your explanation is correct, as is your answer, but your formula is not.

Comment: so you want to account for every arrangement? That's really counterproductive and long

Comment: @ NF Taussig can you tell me whats incorrect

Comment: @Alex i think getting ut in parts is safest as it doesnt miss any thing as im not good at mental calculation:)

Comment: Your cases are mutually exclusive, which means you have to add rather multiply.  The formula you wrote is not equal to $4/15$.  It would be if you had added.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: There's no need for 'mental calculation' (whatever it is). All you need is 3 slots out of 10 allowed), and for every selection of slot multipl by $2!$ to account for BC,CB outcome (which you've done)

Comment: @NF Taussig i had written it in my book and while typing it just slippe off

Comment: By the way, $$\binom{2}{2} + \binom{3}{2} + \cdots + \binom{9}{2} = \binom{10}{3}$$ so your result is equivalent to the one Alex posted.  More generally, $$\binom{n}{n} + \binom{n + 1}{n} + \cdots + \binom{n + m}{n} = \binom{n + m + 1}{n + 1}$$

Comment: Ya so its vandermondes identity am i right

Answer (score 2):

$\binom{10}{3}$ is the number of ways to select 3 slots in 10 possiblee. Now just account for the fact that b and c can interchange for each choice of slots.

EDIT: Once you have done that, multiply by $8!$ (rearrangement of the remaining students) and divide through $10!10$ (total number of arrangements)

Comment: The total number of arrangements is not $11!$ since $A$ cannot occupy the first position.

Comment: apologies, it is $10!10$

Answer (score 2):

When the problem says "Provided $A$ cannot be the first person in line, what is the probability..." it's actually asking for the **conditional** probability that $A$ comes before $B$ and $C$ *given that* $A$ is not the first person in line.  So if we let $E$ be the event that $A$ comes before $B$ and $C$, and $F$ be the event that $A$ is not the first person in line, what we want is

$$P(E|F)={P(E\cap F)\over P(F)}$$

Now what you computed in ${1\over3}-{1\over11}={8\over33}$ is actually the numerator, $P(E\cap F)$.  For the probability the problem calls for, it remains to note that $P(F)={10\over11}$, so that

$$P(A\text{ comes before $B$ and $C$ }|\,A\text{ is not first in line})={8/33\over10/11}={4\over15}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is sure that possibility A comes before B,C is 1/3. But A must not be the first.

$○○CB$

possible A is 1　pattern

$○○○CB$

2 pattern

・

・

・

8 patterns

1+2+・・・8/1+2+3+・・+9

=55-19/55-10

=36/45

=4/5

And then

1/3*4/5=4/15

Answer (score 1):

*Short way:*

As OP has remarked, by symmetry, the probability that $A$ comes before $B$ and $C$ is $\dfrac13$.

The only object that need concern us is the one *immediately* preceding $A$.
(Others won't affect the **probability** computation)

There are $8$ ways with the constraints, as against $10$ unconstrained ways for this object.

Thus $Pr = \dfrac13\cdot\dfrac8{10} = \dfrac4{15}$

---

*Added explanation:*

For constrained arrangements, we know that there are $8$ ways to choose the ball *immediately preceding $A$, both lumped together as a $\huge\bullet$

$B$ (say) can be put next to it in one way: ${\huge\bullet}\Large\uparrow\bullet\uparrow$, but C can now be introduced in $2$ ways.

The next object can now be introduced in **four** ways   $\Large\uparrow{\huge\bullet}\Large\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow$, including before $A$, and for each  succeeding object, the number of ways will increase by one.

Similarly for unconstrained ways, except that it will start with $10$ choices for the object *immediately* preceding $A$, and succeeding objects can be placed on either side.

We thus get $\dfrac {8\times1\times2\times4\times 5\times ...\times 10}{10\times2\times3\times4\times 5\times ...\times 10}$

Apart from the initial $\dfrac8{10}$, the rest of it simplifies to $\dfrac13$,
the symmetric probability that $A$ comes before $B$ and $C$

So we can clearly see the rationale of the *short way*

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities for the places for A, B, C:

1) If they do not include the first place, then there are $\dbinom{10}{3}$ choices for the combined places for A, B, C, and only $\frac{1}{3}$ of the arrangements will have A before B and C.

2) If they do include the first place, then there are $\dbinom{10}{2}$ choices for the combined positions for A, B, C, and only $\frac{2}{3}$ of the arrangements will not have A in the first place.

Therefore the probability is given by $\displaystyle\frac{\frac{1}{3}\binom{10}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\binom{10}{2}}=\frac{40}{120+30}=\frac{4}{15}$.